# Basic 'word learning' site with audio and SQL for storing customer information

Tags: google-apps-for-education

hi I'm looking for the script that already exist, a theme or a guide on how to create a basic website from scratch. A concept is a language learning website that will allow a parent to pick 5 pictures at a time from the gallery, when clicking the picture, a sound 'phonics' is heard. The site should have login signup/register function and SQL to allow the storage of users and query to recall the data. The theme has to be kids colourful friendly have 5 pages,  HTML, CSSM, node.js and PS. Your contribution will be greatly appreciated

I tried to create it myself in VS Code and its difficult

Comment: This is way too broad as currently written.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, tutorials, books, or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. And publishing a specification for a complete application and expecting someone here to provide you with the code is totally unacceptable. This site is for **specific questions** about problems you're having with programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). There is absolutely nothing specific in your question that would make it appropriate to ask here. Come back when you're writing code and ask.

Comment: Also, see [How do I ask (and answer) homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/62576). When you write *The theme has to have 5 pages, HTML, CSSM, node.js and PS.*, it makes it very clear that this is a homework or class assignment, and you need to at least make an effort to do those yourself.